# How to get the sum of a column based on another column (SQL Server 2014)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT 
    HCT_USER_CONTRACT_NUMBER AS ContractNumber, 
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN HIT_CURRENT_STOCK_NUMBER = '_DELIVERY' 
                THEN HIT_CHARGE_AMOUNT 
                ELSE 0 
        END) AS [DeliveryCharge]
FROM 
    TH_HIRE_CONTRACTS C 
LEFT JOIN 
    TH_HIRE_ITEMS I on C.HCT_CONTRACT_NUMBER = I.HIT_CONTRACT_NUMBER
GROUP BY 
    HCT_USER_CONTRACT_NUMBER
```

I am including the above in the select statement but I get an error

> Error converting data type varchar to real

In the `hire_items` table there is multiple lines for each corresponding record in the `hire_contracts` table, and I am trying to return a single line for each hire contract with the sum of the `HIT_CHARGE_AMOUNT` where the `HIT_CURRENT_STOCK_NUMBER= = '_DELIVERY'`. Unfortunately the DB design has a line for each hire item on the contract and in the same table a line for delivery and a line for collection for each hire contract and I just want to get the delivery charges per contract number.

Comment: What are the types of `HCT_CONTRACT_NUMBER` and `HIT_CONTRACT_NUMBER`? Looks like one is a `varchar`, the other `real`. Or else `HIT_CURRENT_STOCK_NUMBER` is a `real`?

Comment: what's the datatype for HIT_CHARGE_AMOUNT within the SUM?

Comment: HCT_CONTRACT_NUMBER and HIT_CONTRACT_NUMBER are INT and HIT_CURRENT_STOCK_NUMBER and HIT_CHARGE_AMOUNT are Varchar

Comment: you'll need to convert/cast the HIT_CHARGE_AMOUNT to a number to be able to SUM it

Comment: @RickyTillson thanks sorry I am fairly new to SQL and have tried a few options of CAST function to try and do this but getting a bit confused as to where it should site around the case statement?

Comment: you need to put the CAST wrapper just around the HIT_CHARGE_AMOUNT, so something like CAST(HIT_CHARGE_AMOUNT AS NUMERIC(12,2)). The general pattern could be SUM(CASE WHEN stuff THEN CAST(column AS NUMERIC(12,2)) ELSE 0 END) AS SumMyColumn. You'll probably want a more appropriate the length of your NUMERIC

Comment: Thanks that sorted it - I had tried something similar and just found that i had misspelled a column name in the join which was causing issues as well!!!!!

Comment: I would strongly suggest you actually change the column type to `decimal` or `float` if it represents a number